# Why does Microsoft Edge not recognize "this*" pointer to object while I use Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, microsoft-edge

Microsoft Edge does not recognize with "this*" pointer in Vue.JS and I got this error:

[Vue warn]: Property or method "*this*" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Keyword "*this*" is used to point to the object of the class it is placed, it is reserved keyword in Vue but MS Edge does not recognize and define it as myself defined object.

How to solve this problem for the MS Edge browser? Thank you.

[Example of using "*this*" in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qNmX.jpg)

Comment: Please show us your code, and please read "how to ask a question".

Comment: Hi, please add details abotu your question following these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, Thank you

Comment: Do you have the keyword {{this}} somewhere in your HTML? please show all code

Comment: The whole file is compiled from Vue.JS files. It has more than 10000 lines. I can not send you the whole thing.

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this issue myself, what I found is that the error happens only with un-minified version https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js, it goes away in https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js.  And it only happens in Microsoft Edge!

I just figured out what worked for me. It happens when you have `this` in your template referencing your data. For example the code below has `this.selectedImages`, I simply removed `this` and the error went away.  Hope this helps.

```
<v-btn @click="editImages"
       color="info"
       v-show="this.selectedImages.length > 0">
            Edit
</v-btn>
```

Comment: Just ran into this myself, and only on Microsoft Edge. The above solution worked.